# VSCode Extension API - event for "text document became dirty/unsaved"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am creating a small VSCode Extension. I found a event that emits when the document is changed:

```
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(function(e) {
        console.log('changed.');
        console.log(e.document.isDirty);
    });
```

However I only want to fire my code if this change turns the document dirty/unsaved. The `onDidChangeTextDocument` event fire for every change. There doesn't appear to be a `onWillChangeTextDocument` event.

Is there a way to ONLY detect the "first" change that changes the document's state from `isDirty: false` to `isDirty: true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made the functionality myself by keeping an array of files changed:

```
var isDirty = [];

function activate(context) {
    console.log('activated.');
    
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(function(e) {
        console.log('Changed.');
        
        if (!isDirty.includes(e.document.uri.path)) {
            console.log('This is the change that made this file "dirty".');
            
            isDirty.push(e.document.uri.path);
            
            // Place code that you only want to run on the first change (that makes a document dirty) here...
        }
    });
    
    vscode.workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument(function(e) {
        console.log('Saved!');
        
        const index = isDirty.indexOf(e.uri.path);
        
        if (index > -1) {
            isDirty.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
    
}
exports.activate = activate;
```

Comment: `e.document.fileName` is not unique, use `e.document.uri.path`

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks! I'll change it.